# Tracking changes in local key set

Tags: hazelcast

What would be the solution for tracking changes in a local key set of IMap? I need to be aware of both put/remove explicit calls and keys migration caused by membership changes (joining and leaving).

Answer (score 0):

You can use interceptors for this, basically `interceptPut`, `afterPut` and `interceptRemove`, `afterRemove`. See http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/3.0/manual/html-single/#MapInterceptor

Comment: Thanks, harsh! The problem is that interceptors are notified only in case of explicit put\remove calls. And.. for the whole distributed map. I'm interested in key set resided on a single (local) member + in all changes (explicit put\get, membership changes, migration, etc.)